# Follow/Unfollow Feature NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to create a follow/unfollow system in my NestJS application. Currently I have a user table and joiner table follows. The follows table has the following structure

follows

| followerId | followingId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |

- followerId the user creating the follow
- followingId the the user who is gaining the follower

I have two routes /follow which creates a record in the follows table and /unfollow which removes a record from the follow tables.

I'm trying to add two relationship properties to user.entity.ts

- followers : User [] all users that follow the user
- following: User [] all users the user is following

then just load these relations when I want to on a user like a profile on twitter.

I referenced this article but its in rails and HasMany doesnt seem to exist in typeorm.
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-a-follow-unfollow-button-in-your-rails-social-media-application-e4081c279bca

Comment: Do you want to have one-to-many relations between user and follows tables for both properties?

Comment: @SoroushAhrari I want to be able to do something like currentUser.followers which gets the users followers and currentUser.following which gets who the user is following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one-to-many relations in TypeORM. Define followers and following properties in user entity as below.

```
@OneToMany(() => Follows, follows => follows.following)
followers: Follows[];

@OneToMany(() => Follows, follows => follows.follower)
followings: Follows[];
```

Also be aware that you can not use OneToMany without ManyToOne on the other side so you have to define the properties below in follows entity.

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.followers)
following: User;

@ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.followings)
follower: User;
```

I believe there are more efficient approaches but based on other parts of your system that you have explained, this should work.

For more information you can checkout the TypeORM [relations](https://typeorm.io/#/relations) docs.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a many to many relation here?

Comment: @ForrestWilkins Yes, for this case it does :)) also it's mentioned in the question that follows is a join table, my mistake. should I edit my answer or you can write another one?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you'll likely want to use a many to many relation, as a user can have multiple followers, and one follower can have multiple "followed users".

```
@ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.following)
@JoinTable()
followers: User[];

@ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.followers)
following: User[];
```

Note that the `@JoinTable` decorator only needs to be added to one side of the relationship.

TypeORM can generate the necessary tables for you, but if you prefer to use your already existing join table, you can try passing options to `@JoinTable()` as shown [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4863).